# Loading JavaScript libraries and css in a typescript Angular 2 webpack project

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js, webpack

I've gone through the substantial effort of setting up an angular 2 project with webpack using npm to store local libraries. I have the app working but I am at a loss for how to load things like jQuery, D3 or bootstrap that I need for my project.

I used

> npm install jquery d3 bootstrap

etc to install the libraries locally but putting them in my vendor file doesn't do much and I cant access the d3 object or css tags from bootstrap inside my angular 2 templates.

my vendor.ts file has these inside them

```
import 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap-loader';
```

I have also tried putting

```
import * as d3 from 'd3/index';
```

in my component file but still dont have access to anything from my angular code.

So basically the question how do you load libraries to the browser with angular2 and webpack?

Edit: My loaders ->

```
       {
            test: /\.css$/,
            include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
            loader: 'raw'
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loaders: ['style', 'css', 'postcss', 'sass']
        },
        {
            test: /\.(woff2?|ttf|eot|svg)$/,
            loader: 'url?limit=10000'
        },
        {
            test: /bootstrap\/dist\/js\/umd\//,
            loader: 'imports?jQuery=jquery'
        }
```

Comment: Please let me know if you could resolve the issue with my seed or with the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing right for import them, the only thing is you need loader for bootstrap fonts and css loader and plugin for jquery.  I have made a angular2 webpack seed based on jquery and bootstrap you can [download](https://github.com/jorawarsingh/angular2-webpack-seed) it and look how it works. In my seed I have a config folder where all the webpack and configurations are.
Your question how you load these libraries in browser well when you are using webpack for bundling it should bundle all the external libraries also into bundle so you can have access in browser. You can configure webpack to make different files like one for the vendor vendors.js one for your app app.js one for the css app.css one for the polymorphism polly.js. there is one issue you are importing bootstrap loader isn't it bootstrap you want like bootstrap.css in that case it's like

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
```

Also check if webpack throwing any errors like it can not fine the modules or if it's unable to bundle because of you need a proper loader for that.

Comment: In my vendor file "import" doesn't seem to do anything. I included that bootstrap line but my markup is still not showing any changes from bootstrap. The vendor file does compile though.

Comment: Is that vendor file included in webpack?

Comment: yes via webpack.common.js - > `module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'polyfills': './assets/js/polyfills.ts',
        'vendor': './assets/js/vendor.ts',
        'app': './assets/js/main.ts'
    },`

Comment: And can you see that webpack is building vendor.js file witch have the your libraries?

Comment: yes when I build - >`vendor-d97dacfa09f7bcd8dbd2.js   3.63 kB     3, 1, 2  [emitted]  vendor`

Comment: Ok let me go to the computer. Do you have code on github?

Comment: https://github.com/bischofs/angular2webpack - I dont have npm modules in my git repo for good reasons.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120550/discussion-between-mrjsingh-and-bischoffingston).